# What do you call somebody who is constantly up-to-date with the latest news?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

A term for an individual who is always aware and knowledgeable of news (international, political, trades, etc.)

Comment: If you are talking about local gossip, you could say they ***have their ear to the ground***.

Answer (score 2):

A term that comes from French but which is used in English is **au courant**.

> knowing about the newest information, trends, etc.
>
> stylish or current

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/au%20courant

> Origin and Etymology of *au courant*:
> French, literally, *in the current*

If you're trying to get your point across as clearly and directly as possible, I would probably just say "informed."

Answer (score 0):

A current term is "**news junkie**". I couldn't find it in a dictionary (at least, not one that wasn't urban...), but this Ngram shows how popular it has become lately.

[image]

[Link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=news%20junkie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnews%20junkie%3B%2Cc0)